# Content Type in share Point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, site-column, content

How to create content type and attach that content type to list?What happens when I delete the particular content type?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-columns-site-columns-or-content-types) is one reference that will give you some brief on **Content Type**.

You can create **Content Type** by two ways:

1. By site settings
2. By hard coding

[Here](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/21/how-to-create-a-content-type-in-sharepoint-2013/) is one reference that will show you that how to create content type and how to attach it to SharePoint list.

When you delete particular content type it will not be used in any other lists.
And if it is used in any other SharePoint lists

> "This content type is already in use"

Now if we want to delete the content type , then

1. normally we first delete the content type association with the list
2. and then we delete the list
3. and finally delete the content type.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Go to [Site settings]-> click on site content types  -> under “Web designer Galleries”.

You can follow this blog to show you how to create content type, 
http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-content-types-in-sharepoint-2013.html

If content type is already attached to some list, it will not allow you to delete it, will give error message like **"This content type is already in use"**

To delete content type first you need to detach it from the associated list.